# Receiving 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null' on all pages other than my index?

Tags: javascript, html, html-framework-7

I am creating an application on Framework7 and am trying to add a section where you can submit text to the browser's local storage. If I use the form and submit the data on my index.html page it works fine, however if I use it in any other page, I get 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null'. I'm linking the script src at the bottom of each page in the same place so I have no idea why I'm getting this error.

HTML

```html
<form>
  Text: <br>
  <input type="text"   id="Input"       name="addText"> <br>
  <button id="Submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```js
var submit = document.getElementById("Submit");

    submit.addEventListener("click", function ()
    {
        var Input = document.getElementById("Input").value;
        localStorage.setItem("Text", Input);
        alert("Your text has been saved");
        console.log("Text saved");
    } , false);
```

Comment: I was able to get your code to work as-is in JS Fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/nyhub7vc/) -- I think something else is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Framework7 has a featured like jQuery and it's called dom7 or $$. You can use the feature like this:

```
$$("#Submit").on("click",function() {
  var Input = $$("Input").val();
  localStorage.setItem("Text", Input);
  alert("Your text has been saved");
  console.log("Text saved");
});
```

Find the documentation [here](http://framework7.io/docs/dom.html#usage-example)

Answer (score 0):

This happens since when you do:

```
var submit = document.getElementById("Submit");
```

`submit` becomes `null`, as the submit button is not available in the other pages.

A quick solution would be to make sure if submit button exists in the current page and only then add the event listener.

```
if(submit){
    submit.addEventListener("click", function () {
        var Input = document.getElementById("Input").value;
        localStorage.setItem("Text", Input);
        alert("Your text has been saved");
        console.log("Text saved");
    } , false);
}
```

Comment: So I added the form on every page, just so that the submit button was on all of my pages. However, I submitted 123456789 into the form on the page I want it on, it now adds `/?addText=123456789` to the URL and doesn't save it to localstorage, any ideas? (Edit: baring in mind it does not do this on my index.html)

Comment: you need to explicitly add a type for the button. It needs to be: <button type="button" id="Submit">Save</button>